# Merge two queries without using union

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to fetch employees who have status in

```
'A-->Active'
L-->Inactive
T-->terminated
```

This status has been defined in a table `lookup_table`. For Active and Inactiev status no other condition is there but for terminated status there is a condition that the term_date can be between today and past 7 days.How can i join these conditions into one query. The query i have written is :-

```
For active active inactive simply :-

select emp_no , full_name
from people_table pt,
lookup_table lt
where lookup_table_type='ASGN'
and pt.assignment_id=lt.code
and lookup_code in ('A','I')

For terminated :-

select emp_no , full_name
from people_table pt,
lookup_table
where lookup_table_type='ASGN'
and lookup_code in ('T')
and term_date between sysdate and sysdate-7
and pt.system_person_type='EX_EMP'
```

How can i merge these two queries into one without using union.

Comment: These queries don't really make sense.  There is nothing matching rows in each table.

Comment: both the rows are fetching from the same table the employee details...... just with the lookup_code't' there are additional conditions

Comment: The first query seems to be, essentially, doing a cartesian product between the two tables.  That is not usually what one intends.

Comment: I have modified my code... hope its fine now

Comment: Do you want rows that are in either query or in both?

Answer (score 2):

```
select emp_no , full_name
from people_table pt,
lookup_table
where lookup_table_type='ASGN'
and (
lookup_code in ('A','I')
or (
and lookup_code in ('T')
and term_date between sysdate and sysdate-7
and pt.system_person_type='EX_EMP' ) )
```

But I guess you did not show us the full code.

Answer (score 1):

To "merge" use an `OR` in your where and you get the same effect.

Like this:

```
select emp_no , full_name
from people_table pt,
lookup_table lt on pt.assignment_id=lt.code
where lookup_table_type='ASGN'
  and (
       lookup_code in ('A','I')
       OR
       (lookup_code in ('T')
        and term_date between sysdate and sysdate-7
        and pt.system_person_type='EX_EMP')
      )
```

Comment: Not working... only those employees are coming with 'A' status

Comment: @user3809240 - lol you changed the code in your question.  ok one sec.